# How to read kotlin annotation

Tags: kotlin, reflection, jvm

I have annotation classes

```
annotation class Endpoint(val name: String)

@Target(AnnotationTarget.TYPE)
annotation class JsonObjectKey(val name: String)
```

These are used like so

```
@Endpoint("my-endpoint")
fun myEndpoint(): @JsonObjectKey("key") String {
    return "value"
}
```

With a `method: java.lang.reflect.Method` object representing `myEndpoint`,
I am able to access the `Endpoint`-Annotation, but I fail to access the `JsonObjectKey`-Annotatation.

`method.annotations` only contains `Endpoint`

`method.annotatedReturnType.annotations` is empty

**How to read `JsonObjectKey`** (`key` in this scenario)?
Intention is to generate JsonObject {"key": "value"}

Comment: Why do you have a `java.lang.reflect.Method`? Why aren't you using Kotlin reflection?

Comment: Method objects are obtained via `https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections`, which is a 100% java library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Kotlin reflection API!

For example, this works:

```
fun main() {
    println(::myEndpoint.returnType.annotations)
}

@Target(AnnotationTarget.TYPE)
annotation class JsonObjectKey(val name: String)

fun myEndpoint(): @JsonObjectKey("key") String {
    return "value"
}
```

This outputs:

```
[@JsonObjectKey(name=key)]
```

If you only have a `java.lang.reflect.Method` for some reason, you can convert it to a `KFunction` using [`kotlinFunction`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect.jvm/java.lang.reflect.-method/kotlin-function.html):

```
println(someJavaMethod?.kotlinFunction?.returnType?.annotations)
```

It appears that annotations annotated in this position in Java:

```
public static @JsonObjectKey(name = "foo") String foo()
```

are very different from those annotated in this position in Kotlin:

```
fun foo(): @JsonObjectKey("key") String = ""
```

These seem to be two different positions. Kotlin reflection cannot see the annotation on the Java return type, and Java reflection cannot see the annotation on the Kotlin return type.

Compare how the annotations appear in the class file. For the Java method, the annotation shows up in the `RuntimeVisibleTypeAnnotations` attribute:

```
RuntimeVisibleTypeAnnotations:
  0: #23(#24=s#20): METHOD_RETURN
    JsonObjectKey(
      name="foo"
    )
```

On the other hand, the Kotlin method instead has the annotation stored as part of the `kotlin.Metadata` annotation:

```
RuntimeVisibleAnnotations:
  0: #86(#87=[I#88,I#89,I#90],#91=I#92,#93=I#94,#95=[s#96],#97=[s#5,s#98,s#76,s#98,s#99,s#100,s#101,s#102])
    kotlin.Metadata(
      mv=[1,6,0]
      k=2
      xi=48
      d1=["..."]
      d2=["main","","myEndpoint","","LJsonObjectKey;","name","key","myproject"]
    )
```

Comment: Great answer. Thanx. Adding dependency to kotlin-reflect and `method.kotlinFunction?.returnType?.annotations` does the trick. @Retention(RUNTIME) is not necessary

Comment: @FrankNeblung Indeed. I didn't know that!